# Laravel count collections within a collection (with a filter)

Tags: laravel

Two realted questions here...

Say I have two models `Owner` and `Dog`, an owner can have many dogs. The dogs also have a field 'color'.

I get all owners with dogs,

```
$owners = Owner::with('dogs')->get();
```

#### 1. How to get the total number of dogs?

With the `$owners` collecton I want to return the total number of dogs.

I could add a count property to the owners model and sum that, but is there another way?

#### 2. How to get the total number of black dogs?

I would also like to get the total number of dogs with a `color` of black.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special function on the Eloquent query builder available called `withCount($relation)`, which basically does the same as `$model->relation()->count()`. The difference is that it eager loads the count for all models in the collection, which yields better performance.

```
$owners = Owner::withCount([
    'dogs as dog_count',
    'dogs as black_dog_count' => function($query) {
        $query->where('color', 'black')
    },
])->get();
```

Eager loading the relation counts will not load the relation itself. So of course you can chain `with('dogs')` to the function as well.

Also you can add class appends  'dog_count','black_dog_count',

```
class Owner extends Model
{

    protected $appends = [
        'dog_count',
        'black_dog_count',
    ];

    public function getDogCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->dogs->count();
    }

    public function getBlackDogCountAttribute()
    {
        return $this->dogs->where('color', 'black')->count();
    }
}
```

And usage

```
$owners = Owner::with('dogs')->get();
$allDogsCount = $owners->sum('dog_count');
$allBlackDogsCount = $owners->sum('black_dog_count');
```

or

```
$allDogsCount = $owners->sum(function ($owner) {
    return $owner->dogs->count();
});
$allBlackDogsCount = $owners->sum(function ($owner) {
    return $owner->dogs->where('color', 'black')->count();
});
```

Comment: I'm not completely sure, but in case you load the full relation through `with('dogs')` anyway, it might be more performant to use `$owner->dogs->count()` and to avoid the additional query to the database. Getting the number of black dogs could be done with `$owner->dogs->where('color', 'black')->count()`. But as stated, I have no idea which one is faster. It most likely also depends on additional constraints, e.g. what indices are available on the database and so on.

Comment: sorry for reverting your `color` fix, I had my edit already written and overlooked yours.

Comment: Makes much more sense after the edit! Hadn't though of getting the data at the query stage. While it hasn't answered my question (getting the counts using the collection) is does achieve what I need. Will wait to see if anyone posts any other answers. Cheers!

Comment: I am updated my answer using appends attribute of model

Comment: Are you wont to get all dogs count, or only user dog count??

Comment: All dogs - the same for all black dogs. Not interested in what each owner has, just the total dogs.

Comment: I updated my answer where getting all dogs count, and black dogs count. I will also update my answer without using 'black_dog_count' and 'dog_count';

Comment: Nice, yeah - that last edit answers the question. Now two options to get the same result! One other thing since asking the question - what if the dogs had ages and I wanted the aveage age of all dogs?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173272/discussion-between-davit-and-steve).